# Set Custom Error Message for Assert (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, assert, webdriver-io

I'm lost in the Node documentation and I'm having difficulties figuring out how I could create a custom (or modify the existing) error handling for all of my assert statements, without having to include individual messages with each assertion.

```
const assert = require('assert');

describe('Test 1', function(){
  describe('Checks State', function(){
    it('will fail', function(){
        assert.strictEqual(true, false);
    });
  });
});
```

As expected, the previous code would just generate something like:

```
1) "Test 1 Checks State will fail"
true === false
```

I'm running with WebDriverIO and my goal is to include the `browser.sessionId` in the error message, **without** having to manually fill in the third (message) parameter on each test.

```
assert.strictEqual(true, false, browser.sessionId);
```

It would be ideal if I could generate an error message like:

```
1) "Test 1 Checks State will fail"
abc012-efg345-hij678-klm901
true !== false
```

I apologize, I know I should include "what I have done so far" -- but everything I've done so far has had no impact.  And again, I'm lost in the node documentation :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot, without tampering with the 3<sup>rd</sup> party lib [`assert`](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html)

Behind the scenes, uses a `fail` function, that is private in the context of `assert` and you cannot tell `assert` to use a custom `fail` function.

this is the function used behind the scenes:

```
function fail(actual, expected, message, operator, stackStartFunction) {
  throw new assert.AssertionError({
    message: message,
    actual: actual,
    expected: expected,
    operator: operator,
    stackStartFunction: stackStartFunction
  });
}
```

As such, you have three options:

1. **(recommended)** [Fork the lib on github](https://github.com/defunctzombie/commonjs-assert). Implement either some watchers like `onFail` or allow it to be extensible and create a pull request.
2. *(not recommended)* Overwrite the `fail` function in the `node_modules\assert\assert.js` file yourself so that, besides triggering the usual stuff, it does what you want as well.

   While quick, **this will cause a broken dependency forever.**
3. Look for other assertions libraries (if there are any that fit your needs)

Answer (score 0):

My answer

```
const assert = require('assert');
describe('Set Custom Error Message for Assert (Node.js)', () => {
    it('Message Assert', () => {
       assert.fail(21, 42, 'This is a message custom', '##');
    });
});
```

[Reference](https://nelsonic.gitbooks.io/node-js-by-example/content/core/assert/README.html)